# Will OpenCV 3.2+ FileStorage save the SimpleBlobDetector_create object in XML or YML?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, file-storage

I am fairly new to OpenCV 3+ in Python. It looks to me that FileStorage under Python does not support, for example, a writeObj() method. Is it possible to save the SimpleBlobDetector_create to an XML or YAML file using OpenCV 3+ in Python?  Another way to put it is this: using Python OpenCV, can I save XML/YAML data that is not a numpy array or a scalar (e.g. an object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making the problem much harder than necessary. The solution is simple:

```
# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change desired parameters
params.minThreshold = 20
params.maxThreshold = 220

# Create the blob detector
detect = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Write detector parameters to .yml file
fs_write = cv.FileStorage('blob_params_modified.yml',
                          cv.FILE_STORAGE_WRITE)
detect.write(fs_write)
fs_write.release()
```

You can read this file in as input instead of fiddling with the code every time you want to tweak a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have lately had some troubles when using FileStorage with XML or YAML (It appears to be some kind of bug in the OpenCV sourcecode). I would recommend you to try it with JSON. In oder to do so, just change the name of the file to XXXX.json. If you are saving self-constructed structures as well, just construct the structure as if it was a YAML and change the filename to .json.

I hope this helps you further.

Regards, David